# Pentaho spoon + redoing field enclosures in output file

Tags: pentaho, spoon

I'm new to Pentaho 8.3 CE (Spoon) and am trying add an extra column to a CSV file by concatenating 3 other text fields together. I'm using 2 options - Calculator and the inbuilt 'Concat fields' transformations.

The issue I'm facing is that some rows are enclosed by " " while others aren't... e.g.

- Field A = "One thing, another thing"
- Field B = Yet another thing
- Field C = Final thing

Ideally, I want,

- New field = "One thing, another thing Yet another thing Final thing",

I find I can't get the final " to enclose each line, so it looks like "One thing, another... Final thing

How do I get Pentaho to add that final " on? I've set to force the enclosure on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZmBj.png)

Comment: Have you tried stripping all quotes and special characters from the strings before concatting? The Text File Output should be able to put them back at the end.

Comment: Tried that  by adding in a 'Replace in string' just after reading the file in. Didn't work

Comment: It works for me with Replace string, no enclosure on Concat fields and quotes enclosure on the text file output, if I **uncheck** right pad fields. I noticed that option is on in your screenshot. Try turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

First strip the double quotes with a String operations step or a Replace in String step (the latter allows regexp search and replace).

The use a Concat strings step to join them all together comma separated.

Finally, either prepend & append double quotes, or when writing out with e.g. a text file output, add the enclosure character.